# How to display model help_text in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have a model with help_text:

```
class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name='Book title',
        help_text='Please enter the book title'
    )
```

In my template it is easy enough to display the book title:

views.py:

```
class BookDetail(DetailView):
    model = Books
    context_object_name = 'book'
```

template.html:

```
{{ book.title }}
```

However, how can I reference the help_text associated with the title model field. E.g. `{{book.title.help_text}}`

Answer (score 0):

```
   from six import text_type

   class Books(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(
                 max_length=255,
                 verbose_name='Book title',
                 help_text='Please enter the book title'
              )
       @property
       def title_help_text(self)
            return text_type(self._meta.get_field('title').help_text)
```

Then you can access `{{book.title_help_text}}` at template.

Comment: six is depreciated in Django 3.0, can you update the example please?

Comment: django.utils.six module is deprecated at Django 3.0, not six module of python. six is not dependent on django.

Comment: Thanks, how would I make this variable so the property looks up any field verbose name I specify in the template?

Comment: Would you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

@alias51, You are using the DetailView which is usually use for display the model data.

Firstly--Need to understand why we need the help_text?

We use help_text to show the additional help information along with the form field.

So its basically use as a hint for input button. i.e:

```
<input type="text" name='title' />
<p>Please enter the book title</p>
```

So you may use help_text in model form if you want to show it as form-field hint or for documentation purpose.

So in class based view you can use it in **CreateView**. where you need to iterate the **form** object:

```
{% for field in form %}
     {% if field.help_text %}
        {{ field.help_text }}
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

For details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#help-text